# Unable to save field collection order of collection that includes entity reference anymore

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I have a Drupal 7 site using field collection and entity reference. The collection includes one entity reference and a boolean checkbox. It is used to related "news" nodes to a page. The checkbox determines if it should show up in a carousel/slider.

We use this collection on a landing page and set it to an unlimited number of these field collections.

This used to work just fine. No idea what changed over the holidays but I came back in today with a message from the client about it. I got on the line with him and he showed it to me. I tried from my admin login and had the same problem.

No errors on the server or in watchdog. I checked apache, php, and mysql error logs. No errors on the page. This is hosted on Acquia for now.

I have cleared cache from the admin and drush. No luck. I am having the same problem with other nodes of this type. We do not use this for any other types of nodes though.

Any ideas as to what could be going on? This did work at one point. And it is clearly not saving these changes.

Answer (score 0):

Actually found that this was caused by a JS error on the page. That explains everything. Fix the JS error, fix the problem.